# Hyperledger Composer ( playground ) not connecting to last chaincode version

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am using Composer and I can successfully deploy chaincode to my infra. The problem is that after any refresh or restart of composer-playground, composer is not reconnecting to the correct version of my chain code so I loose all changes ....
I think I have an issue with the versionning.
Is there any wait to change the "From" version in the composer UI ?

I deployed successfully a first bna on my infra

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is apparently coming from Firefox, same manipulation on chrome works fine and connect to last version of the chaincode. A colleague of mine tried on the same Firefox version as mine and it works fine ! So it's not only an issue with the Firefox version but with my own Firefox. Cache cleaning did not fix it!

Comment: Next try today apparently no, the issue is not only coming frome the browser ... wait and see next dev !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deploying the playground to your local, not sure if you are accessing the playground via the web or not.

Comment: Thanks for you proposal. Yes Deploying on local web version is working fine. My issue is when I connect composer to another infra ( I mean a distant server hosting containers ) I know that I can reach this infra because I see the new container created on it. My issue is that composer doe not connect to the last version. I suspect that the issue is about caching somewhere because if I try to reconnect from a different machine it works (most of the time). I haven't be able yet to identify what cache is involve. Thanks